# Meteor stuck on starting app on android device

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, adb

I have a meteor app that I want to test on my android device. The problem is that 95% of the time the app hangs at "Starting app on android device".

Logs:

```html
Running Cordova app for platform Android with options --device
ANDROID_HOME=/home/john/Android/android-sdk-linux
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).
I20161214-11:04:25.063(2)? Kadira: completed instrumenting the app
I20161214-11:04:25.410(2) (percolate_migrations.js:106) Migrations: Not migrating, already at version 2
=> Started your app.                          
                                              
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/     
I20161214-11:04:25.965(2)? Kadira: successfully authenticated
nulltarting app on Android Device            -
embeddeding app on Android Device            -
org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:17+e            /
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            -                       
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkArmv7DebugManifest
:preX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            -                                   
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            -                                    
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies         -
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            \                                    
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
UP-TO-DATEg app on Android Device            \                             
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE \
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            \                                     
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            |ncLibJarsForDebug                                              
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            |bsForDebug                                              
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:preArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATEice            |
:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
   Starting app on Android Device            |                                      
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
 UP-TO-DATE:packageReleaseResources   Starting app on Android Device            |
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            /                                      
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            /                                   
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            /                                       
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
 UP-TO-DATEAndroidSupportSupportCompat2501Library                                              
 UP-TO-DATEAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2501Library   Starting app on Android Device            /
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2501Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2501Library UP-TO-DATE
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            -1Library                                              
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42501Library UP-TO-DATE
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            -rary                                              
:prepareArmv7DebugDependencies
:compileArmv7DebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            -                              
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            \                              
:mergeArmv7DebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:compileArmv7DebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:generateArmv7DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeArmv7DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
   Starting app on Android Device            \                                     
:generateArmv7DebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            \                            
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            \                         
:processArmv7DebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processArmv7DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateArmv7DebugSources UP-TO-DATE        \
:incrementalArmv7DebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            |                               
:compileArmv7DebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileArmv7DebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:prePackageMarkerForArmv7Debug
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            |                                     
:mergeArmv7DebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            |ebug                                              
:processArmv7DebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForArmv7Debug UP-TO-DATE
:validateDebugSigning
:packageArmv7Debug UP-TO-DATE
 UP-TO-DATE app on Android Device            |                   
:assembleArmv7Debug UP-TO-DATE
:cdvBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 17.072 secs
Built the following apk(s): evice            |
        /home/john/WebApps/agily-app/services/web/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-armv7-debug.apk
Using apk: /home/john/WebApps/agily-app/services/web/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-armv7-debug.apk
Package name: com.idkid0bbrlatmhkpu0ii
   Starting app on Android Device            \
```

I have tried different solutions: reset meteor, reconnect device, restarted adb, updated adb, updated gradle.
Has anyone had this problem and is there a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: You could try running adb logcat from another terminal to see if any error messages come out. You could also try installing the apk from /home/john/WebApps/agily-app/services/web/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-armv7-debug.apk

Comment: Are you adding cordova-related components often or change your apps mobile configs? If not, you could generate an Android Studio project and run it separately. There is no real need to rebuild the app every time you run the server.